# Detecting if I'm running in SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, reflection, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way for my ASP.net Application to know if it's running within SharePoint (2010), but without referencing SharePoint Assemblies? (So I can't just check if SPContext.Current is null).

I wonder if it's viable to get all Assemblies that are loaded by name? So if I see that my AppDomain contains a Microsoft.SharePoint assembly then I know I'm in SharePoint.

Use case: The Assembly runs outside of SharePoint as well, but referencing SharePoint DLLs requires to deploy them (not possibly due to licensing) or getting Exceptions when I access a SharePoint method.

At the moment I use conditional compilation, but I'd like to get away from that and use a DI-mechanism to choose one of two classes, depending if I'm in SharePoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bool isSharepoint =
     AppDomain
        .CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .Any(a => new AssemblyName(a.FullName).Name == "Microsoft.SharePoint");
```

Untested, but this would perform the check for a loaded assemblies whose name was Microsoft.SharePoint.

Comment: Minor quibble: its `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()..`

Comment: Two more things: .Any takes a Predicate so you can get rid of the .Where. Also, the AssemblyName is StartsWith, not == since it's strongly named. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.Sharepoint"));` That's my current approach.

Comment: @Michael Stum, that is why I pass it into the AssemblyName constructor, since MS recommends against manual parsing of FullName "Writing your own code to parse display names is not recommended. Instead, pass the display name to the AssemblyName constructor, which parses it and populates the appropriate fields of the new AssemblyName."

Comment: I think there's a typo in the answer - should probably be `"Microsoft.SharePoint"` (capital P). right?

Comment: @yellowblood: Quick google says you are correct, so I will change, but as I said I don't have a test box to verify for certain.

Answer (score 1):

One way wold be to check the command line parameters of your current process (w3wp.exe) and look for the "-ap "SharePoint Content AppPool". Personally, I prefer the method you mentioned (looking for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll assembly).